# SignalR: Cannot connect to http://localhost:8080 self-hosted server using the full IP address

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm creating a Signal R self-hosted server using the following code:

```
internal class Config
{
    internal static string serverurl = null;
    internal static Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration hubconfiguration = null;
    internal static SignalRHub Hub { get; set; }
    internal static void StartServer()
    {
        serverurl = "http://localhost:8080";
        // In this method, a web application of type Startup is started at the specified URL (http://localhost:8080). 
        {
            Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup>(serverurl);
            Log.AddMessage("Server running on " + serverurl); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.AddMessage("An error occurred when starting Server: " + ex);
        }
    }
}

class Startup
{
    // the class containing the configuration for the SignalR server 
    // (the only configuration is the call to UseCors), 
    // and the call to MapSignalR, which creates routes for any Hub objects in the project.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        try
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            // Enable detailed errors when an exception occures
            Config.hubconfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            Config.hubconfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", Config.hubconfiguration);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.AddMessage("An error occurred during server configuration: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I also created some client applications connecting to this SignalR server via a hub, and everything is working fine when I'm testing on my local computer.

But when I try to connect to the server using the domain computer IP address or the computer name instead of `http://localhost:8080` (from another computer of the domain network or even from my local computer), I'm getting an error as the server cannot be found.

Can you please help me to connect to my SignalR server using the IP address instead of "localhost"?

Comment: The port is probably blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Have you tried switching `serverurl` to "http://{MyIPAddress}:8080"?

Comment: @halter73 Yes I tried to set the serverurl to my domain IP address (`serverurl = "http://192.168.20.24:8080";`) and also to my computer name but I'm getting the following error: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)`

Comment: @halter73 sorry the server url with IP address works when I execute the server with administrator rights

Comment: When I set the server url to my IP address, I can now connect the SignalR clients from my computer but not from other computers of the network, where I'm getting the following error: `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.20.24:8080`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you it was the firewall and the server url!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Setting the server url to `http://{MyIPAddress}:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`
2. Opening the port 8080 by adding a new TCP inbound rule in the Windows Firewall

Comment: hello Please look at my question.,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922658/system-net-http-httprequestexception-was-caught-when-i-try-to-make-a-signalr-h

Comment: Ha, silly me. This is what I needed to remind me that using SignalR in a Xamarin app isn't going to work with `localhost`. Had to figure out the local IP. Maybe this'll help anyone else making the same dumb mistake.

Comment: Hi, could you please shed some light on why can't I specify just localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to automatically set your IP:

```
 <script src="http://<%=Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")%>:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>

 $.connection.hub.url = "http://<%=Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")%>:8080/signalr";
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i resolved by adding Inbound and Oubound Rules for specific port which is being used by serverHub e.g In my case 8080, this port needs to be open for the traffic flowing inward to my machine and outward to the destination e.g serverHub sending massage to all connected clients.